# How old a Consumer Group has to be in order to be considered as "old"

Tags: apache-kafka

"[Kafka: Definitive guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/)" states that:

> Deletion of consumer groups is only supported for old consumer
> clients.

But I could not find anywhere how exactly old should the Consumer Group be. How long should I wait until I can remove the newly created Consumer Group by using `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the text. "Old consumer ***clients***" are those that use Zookeeper (prior to Kafka 0.9)

In any case, as mentioned, you can delete groups manually, but otherwise groups become eligible for compaction after being inactive (meaning, no active consumer group committed offsets for the group) for `offsets.retention.minutes`

Answer (score 1):

From [kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group) i don't see any specification being said that consumer groups should be old in order to be deleted, the only note is to make sure consumers in that group need to be inactive

> To manually delete one or multiple consumer groups, the "--delete" option can be used:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group my-group --group my-other-group

Deletion of requested consumer groups ('my-group', 'my-other-group') was successful.
```

> To reset offsets of a consumer group, "--reset-offsets" option can be used. This option supports one consumer group at the time. It requires defining following scopes: --all-topics or --topic. One scope must be selected, unless you use '--from-file' scenario. Also, **first make sure that the consumer instances are inactive.**